# ¿Cómo pasar un parámetro dentro de un onclick en una cadena?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, materialize

me encuentro con un proyecto de JavaScript, HTML y CSS, y tengo una duda para llamar a una función que tengo en otro archivo llamado ClienteRest. Pongo el código y me explico mejor.

```
mostrarListaEjercicios:function(datos){

  var cadena = '<div id="listaEjercicios"><ul class="collection">';

  for(var i=0;i<datos.length;i++){
    cadena = cadena + '<li class="collection-item avatar"><i class="material-icons circle">create</i>';
    cadena = cadena + '<span class="title">'+datos[i].nombre+'</span><p>'+datos[i].dificultad+'</p>';
    cadena = cadena + '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content" onclick="rest.elegirEjercicio();"><i class="medium material-icons">play_circle_outline</i></a>'
  }
  cadena=cadena+'</ul>';
  cadena=cadena+'</div>';
  $('#messageDiv').append(cadena);
},
```

Esta función la tengo en un archivo diferente al del clienteRest que he dicho, dentro de este archivo rest, hay una función que se llama elegirEjercicio, y se le pasa como parámetro un string `this.elegirEjercicio=function(nombreEjercicio)`. El problema es en como puedo llamar a la función, pasándole el parámetro `datos[i].nombre`, dentro del for, en concreto en el onclick de la última línea del for.

El código de la función en el archivo cliente Rest, sería este:

```
this.elegirEjercicio=function(nombreEjercicio){
  var uid;
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('alu')!=undefined){
    var alu=JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('alu'));
    uid=alu._id;
  }
  if(uid!=undefined){
    $.getJSON(url+"/elegirEjercicio/"+uid+"/"+nombreEjercicio,function(data){           

        console.log("Ejercicio elegido correctamente:"+nombreEjercicio);

        app.mostrarEjercicio(nombreEjercicio);
    });
  }else{
    console.log("No se ha podido elegir ejercicio");
  }
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Dentro de tu html donde esta tu archivo llamado rest.js, arriba manda llamar el archivo ClienteRest.js, y ya con eso mandas llamar tu funcion sin problemas.

Comment: Si si, eso está hecho, tal vez no esté bien formulada la pregunta, lo que no se hacer es pasar el parámetro datos[i].nombre dentro del onclick.

Comment: Pues sería así: elegirEjercicio(datos[i].nombre), o podrias mostrar todo el codigo para entender mejor que es lo que necesitas?

Comment: Vale, subo el nuevo código. Sé como pasarlo, pero el problema es que al estar dentro de una cadena no sabe lo que es datos[i].nombre.

Comment: No logro entender cual es el problema ¿Al estar dentro de una cadena no sabe lo que es datos[i].nombre? ¿A que te refieres? ¿Que datos le estas pasando a la función? Enseñanos un ejemplo de los datos con console.log

Comment: Exacto, si yo pongo `<a href="#!" class="secondary-content" onclick="rest.elegirEjercicio(datos[i].nombre);">`, al estar dentro de la cadena, me dice que datos no está definido.

Comment: Un ejemplo con el console.log(datos), me mostraría: nombre: ______ y dificultad: _____. Datos por tanto contiene varios ejercicios, cada uno con su nombre y su dificultad